# TFS 2013 no burndown chart - SSAS issue when adding role: TfsWarehouseDataReader?

Tags: tfs, ssas, ssms

TFS 2013 does not show burndown charts.

When trying to add report authors to database roles as per following link, it appears there are no roles in the SSMS Analysis Services Roles folder. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb737953.aspx

When (deviating from instructions - step 5 - 7) to add the missing role ("TfsWarehouseDataReader ") by right clicking the following error appears.
[image: SSMS issue when adding role to empty Analysis Services, Roles folder]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like t you analysis services server is all chewed up. I would delete the tfs_Analysis cube and click rebuild in the TFS admiration console.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668753.aspx